# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zIndex' of undefined in Ionic (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

Thanks for watching this question.

I'm doing an ionic app for the city i live. It uses google maps for displaying some information related to the city. Moreover, I want to put custom controls to the map in order to show different types of markers, which are services such as bus stops or hospitals. The problem is that i can't solve this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zIndex' of undefined" and i have tried most of the other answers to this question.

I'm trying to add the element (i think that Legend is its name) inside a controller of my app, just like this:

```
var controlesDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
var controles = new CrearLeyenda(controlesDiv, map);
controlesDiv.index = 4;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controles);
```

Then, outside the controller, i have the *CrearLeyenda* function:

```
function CrearLeyenda(controlesDiv, map) {
controlesDiv.style.padding = '5px 0px';
var controlesUI = document.createElement('DIV');
controlesUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
controlesUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
controlesUI.style.borderWidth = '1px';
controlesUI.style.borderColor = 'gray';
controlesUI.style.boxShadow = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.398438) 0px 2px 4px';
controlesUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
controlesUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
controlesUI.title = 'Click to see Churches';
controlesDiv.appendChild(controlesUI);
var controlesText = document.createElement('DIV');
controlesText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
controlesText.style.fontSize = '13px';
controlesText.style.padding = '1px 6px';
controlesText.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
controlesText.innerHTML = 'Controles';
controlesUI.appendChild(controlesText);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlesUI, 'click', function () {
    alert("clicked");

    if (controlesText.style.fontWeight == 'bold') {
        controlesText.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
    } else {
        controlesText.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    }
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlesUI, 'mouseover', function () {
    controlesUI.style.backgroundColor = '#e8e8e8';
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlesUI, 'mouseout', function () {
    controlesUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
});}
```

I hope you can help me and i'm sorry for my english, i'll try to explain as best as i can if you need more indications.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve the problem just changing `map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controles);` to `map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlesDiv);`. It seems that the other code is OK or, at least, is what is recommended at google maps docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom

This was discovered thanks to duncan

Answer (score 1):

You're calling this as if it were a class constructor returning an object:

```
var controles = new CrearLeyenda(controlesDiv, map);
```

However the CrearLeyenda function doesn't seem to do anything like that.  So the `controles` variable is NULL at this point.  Try adding `console.log(controles);` right after this and see.

I think you need to add this to the end of the `CrearLeyenda` function:

```
return controlesUI;
```

And change how you call it to:

```
var controles = CrearLeyenda(controlesDiv, map);
```

Comment: Thanks for you response duncan, i'll try your solution. Anyway, i just followed this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom As you can see, the function is called with _new_ as an constructor and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Ok, i finally see what was wrong, thanks to your answer. You can call it like that, at least is what appears in the google maps doc, but you have to pass to the map the _controlesDiv_ instead of _controles_. Thanks duncan

Comment: @KevinCifuentesSalas yeah and in that example they could just have called the function without assigning it to a variable, `CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);`